# Dedekind structure of the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, set-theory

Recently, I have come across some materials on the internet, which criticizes the "Dedekind structure" of real numbers and calls this "construction" invalid. For example: you may look up [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSWIFXP2r14&t=3s) (Tell the truth I don't understand what they are saying)

So, my question: Is it worth to take it serious? In other words Does the modern math have some concerns about the "Dedekind structure" of the real numbers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know enough to post an answer, but my two cents: almost all working mathematicians use the real numbers without worrying about their realness. Every construction I know of is equivalent from the perspective of ZFC, so if one is bad, so are the others. That said, the real numbers are pretty weird. Think about it: the numbers you can uniquely describe with a finite string of english words are a countable subset of the real numbers. If the real numbers from $0$ to $1$ were a dartboard, you'd hit one you could describe with a finite string of words with probability $0$.

Comment: Bottom line: to do a whole bunch of math we need a set of numbers that extends the rational numbers so that they're connected in the order topology. The real numbers are the least such set of numbers that do that. We're stuck with them until we develop a different philosophy about how to do some of the most basic math.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesHudgins I appreciate your comments and what you are saying is completely logic for me

Comment: The guy in your linked video is an arrogant ignorant lunatic.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I absolutely agree with you) .There are some other such idiots I have met

Comment: Charles Hudgins has written that mathematicians can use real numbers without worrying about their realness, probably I could add: about their construction. For analyst we need only the list of axioms that $\Bbb R$ satisfies. This doesn't mean I discourage anybody from analysing the construction, since it's very informative and let you sleep well  that reals really exist. However all you need is the list of axioms.

Comment: The American mathematician Underwood Dudley has a book A Budget Of Trisectors about his close encounters with math cranks. (Different editions may have slightly differing titles.) It can be risky. One crank wrote slanderous letters about Dudley to Dudley's department chairman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, my question: Is it worth to take it serious?

No. As a general rule, you can safely skip anything that says "mainstream math is wrong". Also you can skip anything that claims to be a new discovery but isn't published in at least arXiv (there were some exceptions to this, but they are extremely rare).
You can lose some fun but you will never lose any knowledge.

And if something is commonly written in introduction level calculus book (like Dedekind cuts) it's a safe bet that it's correct (modulo some insignificant typos in book).

In the video you linked author for some reason thinks that there should be some fixed number of rational numbers in interval $(0, \sqrt 2)$. Of course it's not so.

If you are curious about Dedekind cut, I would recommend "Principles of mathematical analysis" by Rudin (aka "Baby Rudin"), but it's matter of choice, any decent textbook will work.

Comment: I agree with the Rudin recommendation for Dedekind cuts. Even though it's an analysis book (not a set theory book) the appendix to Chapter One handles Dedekind Cuts more thoroughly than any set theory book I've seen.